# Java Web Services framework

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have the following scenario:
I have to implement web services client that will serve different web services providers with various wsdl-s. Even the same provider can have different versions of wsdl-s that I'll have to support.
We are using java with spring, therefore I was thinking about spring-ws framework. But it seems, that as part of implementation, I have to import wsdl into my project and to write code based on created as part of import pojo-s. So, no problem with different code for different providers, since the logic is different. But I prefer to have the same code for different versions of the same provider and to avoid creation of different versions of pojo-s. 
So, I'm looking for something similar to suds library for python. There you just provide particular wsdl and make a call. You don't deal with wsdl import and different versions of wsdl of the same provider - just need to adjust parameter list of ws call if needed.
Preferable, if spring-ws can do something similar - maybe I just didn't realize that, since now we are trying to get rid of Axis and Axis-2.

Comment: Can you give an example of the differences between the wsdl of the same provider ?

Comment: Lets say, additional parameter added to ws call. In suds you just provide new wsdl and add parameter to the call. You don't have to import wsdl again. It seems that in case of spring-ws you have to keep in a such case 2 different pojos to support different versions, but maybe I'm wrong. My main issue is not adjusting of ws call, but import and keeping different pojo-s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at the [webServiceTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html) ? You have a lot of possibilities and no you do not need to import the wsdl each time. For example you could use a string like this:

```
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(....));
ByteArrayOutputStream  bytArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bytArrayOutputStream);
wsTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source, result); 
final String reply = new String(_bytArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

However this solution is not appropriate on the long run. I will suggest rather using pojos like this

1) In the spring configuration,

```
<bean id="wsTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <property name="defaultUri" value="...."/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.mycompany.app.ws"/>
</bean>
```

2) Create package com.mycompany.app.ws and add a package info

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace = "....")
package com.mycompany.app.ws;
```

3) inside the package com.mycompany.app.ws, you will need to define the request and response.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {})
@XmlRootElement(name = "WsRequest")
public final class WsRequest{
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String requstData;
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {})
@XmlRootElement(name = "WsResponse")
public final class WsResponse {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String responseData;
}
```

4)  In your code do the following:

```
WsResponse wsResponse = (WsResponse ) 
 wsTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(wsRequest_);
```

**What happens if you need to add a new wsdl or new provider ?**

- You can reuse the pojos : You can create another package (for the namespace change) and create a class wsRequest2 that extends wsRequest
- You need to define a new wsTemplate and marshaller in the spring configuration

I think also that you could create a factory that initializes the wsTemplate with the appropriate marshaller.

Comment: So, actually, you suggest using spring-ws and write pojo-s manually including reuse instead of automatic import of different wsdl-s. What I was wondering additionally, again comparing with suds or even with SoapUI: if you have new parameter added to ws, that is actually optional, you can make old type call without this parameter using new wsdl. It works in case if you add mapping of parameters. Example:

Comment: Continuation: Example: wsdl - old: WebService1(param1, param2); wsdl-new: WebService1(param1, param3(optional), param2). You can make a call if you define mapping of parameters: call WebService1(param1=something, param2=something-else) using wsdl-new. The question is if there is similar approach in  spring-ws. So I will be able to cheat a little.

Comment: @Nata Assuming that the namespace does not change, yes, you could the same object and mark the optionnal value with "required=false"